# oclint not install in Mac machine

Tags: ios, objective-c, oclint

I want to install Oclint so that it can review objective C code. Can any one has it's tutorial or share any step by step guide line for how can we install it and check objective c code by it.

I read this link 
http://docs.oclint.org/en/stable/intro/installation.html
and tried 2 options but still 'oclint' not installed. Can any one suggest me.